# Why wrap every prototype "class" object with an anonymous function in JS?

Tags: javascript

Looking at [this JS code](https://github.com/davidfowl/BombRMan/blob/master/BombRMan/Scripts/assman.js) by David Fowler he wraps every "class" with an anonymous self executing method where he sends in jQuery and window. I get that this is a way for ensuring that $ and window are actually the global jQuery and winndow variables you'd expect them to be.

But isn't this a bit over-protective? Should you protect yourself from someone else changing the $ and window variable - is there actually code that does that, and if so why? Also, are there *other* advantages to wrapping everything like this?

Comment: Moving `window` to function scope also means that minifiers can replace it with a shorter variable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of using *function context* to create local / *function scopes* is all about to protect your own code. This especially makes sense if you expect your Javascript code to run in an environment where multiple other (maybe even unknown) scripts may get loaded.

So, if some other Javascript code which got load before your own, assigns `window.$` with some other value (it might load the *prototype framework* for instance), then your code is already screwed if you try to access jQuery specific things.

Another point there is the "*a--hole*"-effect. Someone creates a line like

```
window.undefined = true;
```

...
Now, all your checks against `undefined` will pretty much fail. But by explicitly creating those variables/parameters and filling them with the values you expect, you can avoid all those problems.

```
(function(win, doc, $, undef) {
}(window, window.document, jQuery));
```

Comment: JavaScript code cannot be run simultaneously or parallel with other JavaScript code.

Comment: @Domenic: well, I hoped the point was clear. I actually just meant that there might other scripts which gets loaded before and after your own scripts, it was not about execution time itself.

Comment: what if code like `window=document=null,` executes before your scripts??

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly there are some other libraries than jQuery using the $.

Answer (score 2):

Generally most top-level JavaScript code should be wrapped in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), whether they pass in particular variables or not. This prevents variables created with `var` from polluting the global scope.

Another small benefit is minification: if you minify your code, making `window` into a "local variable" by passing it in as a parameter allows the minifier to rename it. This benefit goes away if you gzip, however, so it's not a real win.

Mostly people just pick a pattern for their IIFEs and stick with it, so in his case he's decided this is they way he writes his `.js` files and he does so uniformly. Having a uniform standard is valuable in and of itself.

To clarify, the code can be written in slightly longer form with

```
(function () {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var window = window;

    // ...
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the anonymous function is the the function scope, so it prevent confliction with the global variables.

Imaging that if every jQuery plugin is not wrapped in a anonymous function, then there will be a global variables hell.

Answer (score 0):

It's just to preserver integrity.
$ can be Prototype, so sending jQuery as argument will save your code if someone else add a library/variable which overwrite $.

About the second argument "window", I see it as a module you want to write on.